# Simulink matlab function block

Tags: matlab, simulink

How do I display the current value of a variable in the matlab command window? In matlab I usually use `disp(var)` and it will output the variable value into the command window. However in the MATLAB function block if I were to enter `disp('hello')` it doesn't show any output in the command window. I am using matlab 2014b.

Comment: Simulink works separately and differently from MATLAB. Why would you want to do this? small simulations can take +1000000 iterations ("steps") in Simulink, you will clog your command window

Comment: i want to see the values the variables have, because i keep getting the error that one of them is trying to access an array element of size greater than it can. This doesn't make sense to me since I feed three inputs (of which two are constants) into a bus and use that as the input for the function block. However it the function block doesn't seem to see the three inputs.

Comment: you need a [mcve]. You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You idea for displaying output value in the command window is not a good approach to solve your issue. I would suggest you look at [`scope block`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/scope.html) if you'd like to see the value during simulation. Or use [`To Wrokspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html) block if you'd like to output the value into main workspace.

For debugging your code and design, read and use [Simulink Debugger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/debugging.html) should be helpful.